# Converting column to float in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been stuck for a long time on this problem:

I am reading some data from a .csv file, and some numeric elements have been saved as a list, with comma as a thousand separator. Also, the data includes some NaN.

So first I'm loading the csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
```

Then I'm looking at the head:

```
df.head()
index   val
0       ['12,345,678.90']
1       ['2,345.67']
2       NaN
Dtype: Object
```

My goal is to have this column with a Dtype = Float64, something that looks like this:

```
df.head()
index   val
0       12345678.90
1       2345.67
2       NaN
Dtype: Float64
```

For now, I tried the following:

**Using a lambda**

```
df['val'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', '')).astype('float')
```

And I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. The Dtype of my column is "dtype('O')", meaning it is an "object" (string). Maybe NaN is being considered as a Float ?

**Defining a custom function and applying it:**

I got this approach from [this article](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html), which is great.

So I am defining my function like this:

```
def convert_float(val):
     new_val = val.replace(',','').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", "")
     return float(new_val)
```

And then I call it on my data:

```
df['val'] = df['val'].apply(convert_float)
```

But I am still getting the same error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

**Iterating over the rows in order to make the modification:**

I feel like this is not the best practice, I know that doing such an iteration is computationally expansive, but I was still not able to get it to work, and I'm trying to know why.

I wrote the following code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['val'] = float(row['val'].replace(',','').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", ''))
```

But when calling it, I'm still getting the same error:

```
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I also tried to test if the value is NaN in order to only perform the operation on the non-NaN values:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(not pd.isna(row['val'])):
        row['val'] = float(row['val'].replace(',','').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", ''))
```

And it works ! I don't get any error this time, however my Dtype is still "Object".

Is it that I should handle NaN differently ?
What is the best practice in order to handle such a situation when loading a csv ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in the end i found the answer: simply casting the type to "str".

I am not sure why it initially considers NaN as Float, but the following code achieves what I'm trying to do:

```
df['val'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', '').replace("'", "")).astype('float')
```

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

I got here a little late, but you don't even need to use apply or lambda for this

```
df2['val'] = df2['val'].str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '').str.replace("'", '').str.replace(",", '').fillna(0).astype(float)
```

doing all this on the same variable gives you the same result

Answer (score 0):

find the digit and '.' and join together.

```
obj = df['val'].fillna('').str.findall('\d+|\.').str.join('')
obj[obj == ''] = np.nan
df['val'] = obj.astype(np.float)
```